# Create Objects from Json dynamically in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, decode

I need to know some if it is possible to create objects from JSON in this way:

Let's suppose I got 2 objects Human and Animal, Human will have as attributes name, age, sex and Animal name, legs, colour.

I store the information in a MongoDb and when I retrieve something using a query I receive the result in Json

```
human = {'name':'Bogdan','age':'21','sex':'male'}

animal = {'name':'Bob','legs':'4','colour':'brown'}
```

Ok. Now it comes the question .. I want to decode the Json using a function and create objects from them, something like this :

```
def object_decoder(object, jsonToConvert):

 return object(**json.loads(jsonToConvert))
```

It is a good practice to try an abstraction of this functionality, or it is better to make a object_decoder function for every Object Model.

Thank you!

Comment: You may be surprised to learn that python has a json module. Try searching "python json".

Comment: What is this? `human = {'name':'Bogdan','age':'21','sex':'male'}` what is `type(human)` after this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure

```
class Thing:
     def __init__(self,**kwargs):
         for k,v in kwargs.items():
             setattr(self,k,v)
     def __getitem__(self,item):
         return self.__dict__.get(item,None)
     def __repr__(self):
         return "<Thing: %s>"%self.__dict__

Thing(**json.loads('{"name":"Bogdan","age":"21","sex":"male"}'))
```

in reality you probably shouldnt really do this...unless you have a good reason to.

classes are typically used when you want to encapsulate **some behaviors** along with stateful data.
when you just have data then a dictionary is just fine(your example is only data so no real point in a class) ...

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why this is not a good practice?

Comment: @BogdanMursa see the edit, however you may also want to look into YAML which allows you to serialize and deserialize custom classes and datatypes (at some speed cost of coarse)

Answer (score 1):

No need to decode, simply enable to construct the object from a `dict`, **or better**, if you can - use the keywords as the field names you're using in mongo.

Then, just use:

```
import ast
class Human(object):
    # same as mongo
    def __init__(self, name=None, age=None, sex=None):
        print name
        print age
        print sex
# you should be able to get these as dicts straight away...
human = {'name':'Bogdan','age':'21','sex':'male'}
human_obj = Human(**human)
```

I'm not sure what the object type you're mapping is, so I added what I thought. If you have a dict - it's best.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is about as fast as naive `import json`(actuaqlly a little faster) however the best way to read this data is `import simplejson as json`

Comment: @JoranBeasley , I wasn't sure what the object is, since what he printed isn't the output I know from the `json`. Obviously using `json` is preferable. See the bottom line I added. And thanks for the info, I just learned about `ast.literal_eval` recently.

Comment: simplejson blows the other 2 away in terms of performance (yeah ast.literal_eval is cool ... and when I first learned about it it seemed awesome and I tried to use it everywhere (when you have a hammer everything looks like a nail))

Comment: Again, I didn't understand what the object is since he said he is getting it from a database. I'd never use `literal_eval` for a `dict`. Actually, I'd avoid it anywhere I can. ++ fixed answer to fit to `dict`